# If I replace my GPU will Win10 still recognise my PC as having a valid license?

Tags: windows-10, license

I read Win10 ties the free license that comes with upgrading from Win7 to the hardware configuration. If I replace my GPU will it still recognise my PC as having a valid license?

Comment: Typically Windows licenses are attached to the motherboard only, at least in previous versions of windows. I'm curious to know this as well, although I suspect it may just be the same as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your license will still be valid.

The license is tied to the motherboard. Replacing the GPU or any other removable device will not invalidate your license or cause you to have to reactivate.

If you still have a Windows 7 product key, you should be able to activate Windows 10 with it for the time being, if you ever had the need to reinstall Windows or change motherboards.